# Code First Model Association Behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two simple objects, Foo, and FooAttribute. These used to be in an EDMX, but I am working on migrating to Code First. I have previous code that associates the two like so:

```
var foo = new Foo();

var fa = new FooAttribute() {
   Foo = foo
}
```

And in EDMX land, after running this code, `foo.FooAttributes` will have a reference to the newly created `FooAttribute`.

This does not appear to work in Code First. If I run the previous code with code first set up, the new FooAttribute does not get persisted to the database. It appears I have to do so:

```
var foo = new Foo();

var fa = new FooAttribute();

foo.FooAttributes.Add(fa);
```

Is that the only way to add references in code first? Or will I have to rewrite a significant amount of code to find all the places where this happens?

Comment: this is the correct way to add it to the dbcontext but you can do also something like that: context.Entry(FooAttribute).State = EntityState.Added;  do the same for Foo

Comment: @BassamAlugili Unfortunately that still involves finding every single place this pattern is used in the codebase and tagging it as a tracked entity.